# How to recursively map one nested object type to another

Tags: c#

I would like to map the data from one list of objects and another. I am looping through CompanyAEmployee list and able to map FullName and Title. But not able to map Children property.

```
public class CompanyAEmployee
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<CompanyAEmployee> Children { get; set; }
 }

public class CompanyBEmployee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PositionName { get; set; }
    public List<CompanyBEmployee> Children { get; set; }
}

companyAEmployeeList; // stores all employees of companyA
var companyBEmployeeList = new List<CompanyBEmployee>();

foreach(var employee in companyAEmployeeList)
{
   var companyBEmployee = new CompanyBEmployee();
   companyBEmployee.Name = employee.FullName;
   companyBEmployee.PositionName = employee.Title;
   //how to map the children??
}
```

Can someone suggest a way to map Children?

Comment: Following will give one layer children.  You would need to use a recursive method for getting multiple levels : var employees = companyAEmployeeList.SelectMany(x => x.Children.Select(y => new {Name = x.FullName, Title = x.Title, ChildName = y.FullName, ChildTitle = y.Title}).ToList());

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recusive method, like below:

```
public CompanyBEmployee ComAToComB(CompanyAEmployee a){
    CompanyBEmployee b = new(){
        Name = a.FullName,
        PositionName = a.Title,
        Children = new()
    };
    foreach(var child in a.Children){
        b.Children.Add(ComAToComB(child));
    }
    return b;
}
```

And then call it like

```
var comB = ComAToComB(comA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
public class CompanyAEmployee
        {
            public string FullName { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public List<CompanyAEmployee> Children { get; set; }

            public static explicit operator CompanyBEmployee(CompanyAEmployee employee)
            {
                CompanyBEmployee employee1 = new CompanyBEmployee();
                employee1.Name = employee.FullName;
                employee1.PositionName = employee.Title;
                employee1.Children = new List<CompanyBEmployee>(employee.Children.Count);
                int count = employee.Children.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    employee1.Children[i] = (CompanyBEmployee)employee.Children[i];
                return employee1;
            }
        }

        public class CompanyBEmployee
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string PositionName { get; set; }
            public List<CompanyBEmployee> Children { get; set; }
        }
```

Now you can just use an assignment operator with explicit casting from CompanyAEmployee to CompanyBEmployee.
Like this:

```
CompanyAEmployee employee = new CompanyAEmployee(); 
//... assign all the fields
CompanyBEmployee employee2 = (CompanyBEmployee)employee.
```

Now you are done!

Answer (score 0):

So, in my case it was best solution to use extension methods.

You can see example here

https://dotnetfiddle.net/SwhGMY

Main idea is to use such extension method that was called recursively.

```
public static class ClassConverterExtensions
{
    public static CompanyBEmployee ToCompanyBEmployee(this CompanyAEmployee that)
    {
        var result = new CompanyBEmployee();
        
        result.Name = that.FullName;
        result.PositionName = that.Title;
        
        if(that.Children == null)
        {
            return result;
        }
        
        result.Children = new List<CompanyBEmployee>();
        
        foreach(var item in that.Children)
        {
            result.Children.Add(item.ToCompanyBEmployee());
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
}
```

Good point is that you can write this without changing source code of classes `CompanyBEmployee`  and `CompanyAEmployee`

So, this classes is not referenced one to another, but you can write converters From A to B and from B to A without cyclic references.